# Show that the multiplication operator $M_a$ is invertible in $L_p (\mathbb{R}^n) $ iff $a \neq 0$ almost everywhere and $(M_a)^{-1} = M_{a^{-1}}$

Tags: operator-theory, inverse

I mean, it's basically trivial, because

$$M_a f = a(x) f(x)$$

And the only other operator $X$ to satisfy $X M_a f = M_a f X = If$ is $X = M_{a^{-1}}$, thus $(M_a)^{-1} = M_{a^{-1}}$, because $a (x) \cdot a^{-1} (x) = id$.

Is this really it? Because I kind of feel that there must be some sort of a twist, as this alone cannot really be the solution to that exercise?

Comment: Not every measurable function $a$ makes $M_a$ a bounded operator on $L^{p}$. In fact $a \in L^{\infty}$ is necessary and sufficient. But $a \neq 0$ a.e. does not imply that $\frac 1  a \in L^{\infty}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy this exercise is only for $p < + \infty$